# how to retrieve data in nested json format from Mysql database in .net core?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

**I want to retrieve data from MySQL database like this **

[Data formate is in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS620.png)

for that should I create class like this

```
public class main
{
    public string name { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<sub1> child1 { get; set; }
}


public class sub1
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<sub2> child2 { get; set; }
}

public class sub2
{
    public string mname { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<sub3> child3 { get; set; }
}

public class sub3
{
    public string lname { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<sub4> child4 { get; set; }
}

public class sub4
{
    public string name1 { get; set; }
            public string name2 { get; set; }
}
```

And how I get data from database in given format using stored procedure ???
And currently I am able to read data in simple json format using Mysqldatareader but I don't know how to read nested json data so can anyone help me ???

I can able to read data like this

```
read.CommandText = "getdata";
                read.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                read.Connection = connsql;
                connsql.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = read.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        datas.Add(new data
                        {
                            name1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")),
                            name2 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Lname")),
                                                                                                                    });
                    }
                }
```

*getdata* is my stored procedure

Comment: Can you also share the how the data in table look like? And what is the criteria to do decide which is the child and which is parent? Did you write any code for that? Please share that code too...

Comment: I would suggest using a [Json deserializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) to convert the Json

Comment: In database table there is unique id which is primary key based on that I retrieve data from table

Comment: should I need to store data in different table or two table is fine ??